# JavaScript regexp for GIT diff

Tags: javascript, regex, git

I'm working on something that requires JS regex pattern matching given a GIT diff string. Below is some example code I have:

```
var diff = [
    'diff --git a/index.txt b/index.txt',
    'index 7e18d52..0c11620 100644',
    '--- a/index.txt',
    '+++ b/index.txt'
].join('\n')

var path = '(\\/)?([^\\/\0]+(\\/)?)+'

var regexp = [
    'diff\\s\\-\\-git\\sa\\/' + path + '\\sb\\/' + path,
    'index\\s\\w+\\.\\.\\w+\\s\\w+',
    '\\-\\-\\-\\sa' + path,
    '\\+\\+\\+\\sb' + path
].join('\\n')

regexp.test(diff)
```

When I run the code it just sits there. I've waited as long as 5 minutes before stopping testing. However If I change the example code to look like this:

```
var diff = [
    'diff --git a/index.txt b/index.txt',
    'index 7e18d52..0c11620 100644',
    '--- a/index.txt',
    '+++ b/index.txt'
]

var path = '(\\/)?([^\\/\0]+(\\/)?)+'

var regexp = [
    new RegExp('diff\\s\\-\\-git\\sa\\/' + path + '\\sb\\/' + path),
    new RegExp('index\\s\\w+\\.\\.\\w+\\s\\w+'),
    new RegExp('\\-\\-\\-\\sa' + path),
    new RegExp('\\+\\+\\+\\sb' + path)
]

regexp[0].test(diff[0]) && regexp[1].test(diff[1]) && regexp[2].test(diff[2]) && regexp[3].test(diff[3])
```

Add then run the code, it finishes almost immediately (and with a successful match). Ideally the first version of my code would complete as fast as the second version so I'm wondering why their execution times are so different. Could someone offer some insight? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't just tack a bunch of expressions together with line breaks and expect it to match the same way as the individual expressions, at least not without accounting for the lines in your expression (especially in ranges and regexp flags).

Comment: But in a git diff each line is separated by a line break `\n` so how does it change the regex by adding a check for the line break in the concatenated regex?